# How to configure extended app authenticity in IBM Mobile first studio?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While deploying application file app-android-1.0.wlapp to worklight console page the following warning message displayed. The app was not deployed to the console page..
FWLSE3123W:Environment Android of application version 1.0 has been deployed with extended application authenticity disabled. It is recommended to use extended app authenticity to further protect from unauthorized apps by using the enable extended authenticity command of the wladm tool before deploying application...
Even I followed the below link..
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_enabling_extended_authenticity_checking.html

I don't know how to configure in .wlapp file

Answer (score 0):

The development server that is used in MobileFirst Studio **does not** support Application Authenticity Protection. The feature is available only for applications that are deployed to an external Tomcat/WAS full profile/WAS Liberty profile.

The warning is there to let you know that you did not enable Extended Authenticity.

To enable it, you need to follow the steps as described in the following tutorial once you move to an external application server: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/

Take note of the section "Enabling extended application authenticity protection", which says the following:

> To enable extended authenticity checking, you must deploy a modified
>   .wlapp file, instead of the original .wlapp file that is generated by
>   the build process.
>
> Modify the .wlapp file by using the wladm program or the wladm Ant
>   task:
>
> *By using the wladm program* Use the wladm program (provided in the MobileFirst installation directory) to run the enable
>   extended-authenticity command:
>
> ```
> wladm enable extended-authenticity src-wlapp-file device-file > dest-wlapp-file
> ```
>
> src-wlapp-file => Original binary app file (.wlapp) device-file =>
>   Binary mobile app file (.apk, .ipa, or .xap) dest-wlapp-file => Output
>   binary app file (.wlapp)
>
> After running the wladm , deploy the output file to MobileFirst Server
>   instance.
>
> *By using the wladm Ant task* Use the wladm Ant task (provided in the MobileFirst installation directory) to run the
>   enable-extended-authenticity command:
>
> ```
> <enable-extended-authenticity srcwlappfile="original-.wlapp-file"
>     devicefile="device file(.apk, .ipa, or .xap)"
>     destwlappfile="output-.wlapp-file"/>
> ```
>
> After running the wladm command or Ant task, deploy the output file to MobileFirst Server instance.

Comment: Hi idan, i done that extended authenticity for Android app. But i have another error while uploading android app myapp-android-1.0.wlapp with extended authenticity to console page it's not uploading. In error log The transaction has been rolled back. See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred

Comment: Hi Adar, Were can i find the library for enable-extended-authenticity ANT Task in the MobileFirst installation directory. My Ant Task not able to find the enable-extended-authenticity in worklight-ant-builder.jar